# How to find the maximum length of data in a particular field in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "Users" and one of the column is "USERNAME". I am trying to find out the maximum length of the username by comparing all the usernames. I need this max value to use for another query. I tried

```
SELECT  max(length(users.username)),username 
FROM users group by username;
```

returns all the rows.

Example:

```
 USERNAME
----------
Tara  
Amyamyse  
Tommy  
John
```

I would like to get the result as below:

```
MAX_Length     USERNAME
--------------------
  8             Amyamyse
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another option:

```
select username, length(username) as username_length
from users
where length(username) = (select max(length(username)) from users)
```

This would return multiple users in case there be a tie for the longest username.  If you have specific rules for breaking a tie then update your question.

Comment: Yes,It lists out two usernames. The table has two records with the same username. The output gives only the username not the length. How can I get both the length and the username ?

Comment: Just add `length(username)` to the `select` clause.

Comment: I have asked a dumb question. Added lenght(username) in the select part to get the output that I need and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

another possability to avoid mass-use of functions:

```
SELECT
     username
   , length(username)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    username
ORDER BY
    length(username) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have use a subquery because the group by will prevent desired results if you were to use a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT name, LENGTH(name)
FROM your_table
WHERE LENGTH(name)=( SELECT MAX(length(name)) FROM your_table)
GROUP BY name
```

additionally you can test the answer on this sqlfiddler
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0ff8/5

Comment: Tried this and the output lists out all the rows with length.

Comment: I originally misunderstood what you where trying to accomplish, I've updated my answer